# Set alignment of QGroupBox title

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I try programmatically set alignment of title of QGroupBox. According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#alignment-prop) I try to do it in the following way:

```
MainWidget::MainWidget (QWidget * parent)
            : QWidget (parent)
{
    setWindowTitle (tr ("QGropBox Title Alignment issue") );

    QGroupBox * group = new QGroupBox ("Group Title", this);
    QVBoxLayout * layoutTop = new QVBoxLayout ();
    layoutTop->addWidget (group);
    group->setAlignment (Qt::AlignHCenter);
    this->setLayout (layoutTop);
}
```

But I have got unexpected result and title aligned with the left-hand side of the group box.

[image]

Such behaviour I have got with the environment:

- Debian 9.0 (sid);
- Qt 5.5.1 (installed from repository);
- XMonad DE.

[image]

The same behaviour I have got with the next environment:

- Ubuntu 15.10;
- Qt 5.4 (installed manually using offline-installer);
- KDE.

But! If I use Qt installed from repository (Qt 5.4.2) the title will aligned with the centre by default. But if I change align to the left it will not changed.

I try find some solution with Google, but I haven't found similar questions and this is bad sign and usually this is means that I do some thing wrong.

So my question is: Why I can't manage by alignment of the group box title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in Qt 5.5.1 there is a bug for some visual styles when QGroupBox title alignment is not taken into account when title's rect is computed: [QTBUG-49068: QGroupBox title does not follow alignment with fusion style](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49068).

You can download most recent version from git repository, build it and check if the bug has been fixed (is has been for Fusion style: [qt commit 139953](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/139953/)).

If bug still occurs, I think you should submit an issue to Qt [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/).

Comment: I've tried lunch my example with different `-style` options. With `fusion` and `gtk` the problem exists, but wiht `windows` it doesn’t.