# how to setAlignment of QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, alignment

I want to set the alignment of a `QGroupBox` title to the left but it stays centered. What I've tried is:

```
QGroupBox *groupBox = new QGroupBox(tr("Test"), parent);
groupBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

any idea how I can get this aligned accordingly?

'

Comment: Its working fine for me on mac, Is there any stylesheet applied ? If your application is setting stylesheet globally , stylesheet can override the alignment done by code.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278133/set-alignment-of-qgroupbox-title) helps.

Comment: @sanjay no, i don't set any particular stylesheet...